# Angular - Validate an entire row of inputs in a table

Tags: angularjs, validation

All,

I am using Angular and have a validation situation to which I have not yet found an answer. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

I have a 5 row by 4 column grid. Each row represents a single object, and the user can submit from 1 to 5 of the objects. An object must be complete, so if a user fills out fewer than 4 of the columns for a given row, the row and form is invalid and the user should be shown which fields are in error.

All constructive thoughts, comments, and/or alternatives are welcome.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the documentation on [forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) particularly the CSS classes. You can make your whole table one form. Then on submit check for these classes. The classes would probably be the way to go if you want to give user feedback because you can have styles for ng-invalid for instance. Also, you can get some input type validation like phone, email, etc. for free.

Alternatively, I assume you are using data binding for these inputs. So on submit of your form you can just validate the models on the javascript side before proceeding.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I forgot about using the classes as row identifiers. Good call. As it turns out, we wound up with an entirely different requirement for the form, so the issue becomes somewhat moot, but at least I can keep this one in the files if/when it comes around again.